# error while installing RVM (gpg key problem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, rvm, gnupg

I am trying to install RVM on my ubuntu system using this blog. https://rvm.io/

when I run these command

```
gpg2 --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

I am getting this problem.

```
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/archive/1.29.9.tar.gz
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/releases/download/1.29.9/1.29.9.tar.gz.asc
gpg: Signature made Wednesday 10 July 2019 02:01:02 PM IST
gpg:                using RSA key 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
gpg: Good signature from "Piotr Kuczynski <piotr.kuczynski@gmail.com>" [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: 7D2B AF1C F37B 13E2 069D  6956 105B D0E7 3949 9BDB
GPG verified '/usr/share/rvm/archives/rvm-1.29.9.tgz'
tar: binscripts: Cannot utime: Operation not permitted
tar: config/solaris: Cannot utime: Operation not permitted
tar: config: Cannot utime: Operation not permitted
tar: contrib/hudson: Cannot utime: Operation not permitted
tar: contrib: Cannot utime: Operation not permitted
tar: docs: Cannot utime: Operation not permitted
```

I think keys are not working. Does anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the ubuntu `rvm package` is already installed and you are trying to install `rvm` again. If you installed using the package, there is no need to run the manual install steps, `rvm` will work.

To remove the package, just use `sudo apt purge rvm`. After it finishes, check if you have any presence of `/usr/share/rvm` and delete the folder in case it's present.

After that, you can get the latest `rvm` through the steps you are already doing.